# What kind of values are template parameters? What can I (not) do with them?

Tags: c++, templates, value-categories

Can a value be assigned to a template non-type parameter?

For example

```cpp
template<int N>
void foo(){
    N = 4;
}
```

Trying to compile this I get:

```sh
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
     N = 4;
       ^
```

What kind of values (Value Category) are template parameters, and how much can I "play with them" in function bodies? (I.e. reading them, writing to them, forwarding them to other template parameters, printing them, etc).

For example, what is the correct way of creating a function template that "registers" a number (passed as template parameter at compilation time) and then prints that number every time it is called (at run time)?

Comment: You have to know that template is nothing but to substitute. In the non-type template case (or value template here), the compiler would use some int value (say `5`) to substitute `N` and generate a function. Hence, you cannot assign any value to `5`.

Answer (score 2):

They are approximately equivalent to literals with the given value. In C++20 there is a concept [`LiteralType`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType), which is a requirement for being a non-type template parameter.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters)

> When the name of a non-type template parameter is used in an expression within the body of the class template, it is an unmodifiable prvalue unless its type was an lvalue reference type

From [the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#6)

> A non-type non-reference template-parameter is a prvalue. It shall not be assigned to or in any other way have its value changed. A non-type non-reference template-parameter cannot have its address taken. When a non-type non-reference template-parameter is used as an initializer for a reference, a temporary is always used.